# Qt: Styling QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget

I'm using Qt and I have a QTabWidget setup in the Qt Designer Editor, you can see it in picture 1.

[image: picture 1]

As you can see after Tab4 there is an empty space all the way to the right edge, in someway I need to fill that space with a color, like in picture 2 (the best thing would be to be able to set a fading color). Or another solution would be that the tabs float out to cover the whole screen.

[image: picture 2]

I use the following stylesheet right now:

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {

 }

 QTabBar::tab {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 QTabBar::tab:selected {
  background: lightgray;
 }
```

Is there a way to set the background color of the QTabBar using Qt stylesheets? Or can I get the tabs floating out to the edge using Qt stylesheets?

EDIT:
I have been trying the solution that Caleb Huitt - cjhuitt suggested below. I really like the idea of making the tabs expand but can't get it working.

In Qt Designer Editor I right click on my QTabWidget->"Promote To ..." and choose "Base class name": QTabWidget
"Promoted class name": ExpandableTabWidget
and then I click add and then Promote.

In the init method of the widget that holds my QTabWidget I set

```
ui.tabWidget->SetTabsExpanding(true);
```

Everything is building fine but the QTabbar doesn't expand.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried giving tab-bar a background-color ? what was the result ?

Comment: Yes, tested that but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! But thats what I've been playing with so far but no results. Isn't this possible?

Comment: The Q_PROPERTY line will probably only help you if you make the expanding tab widget into a plugin.  Otherwise, if it is generating warnings, you could remove it.

Comment: Also, regarding the expanding tab widget, I was assuming that this would work, never having done it myself.  If it doesn't work, you could create your own tab widget pretty easily, with a QTabBar above a QFrame, and a QStackedWidget inside that QFrame.  You'll need to add some logic to handle the switching, of course.  However, I'd poke around a little more to try and find out why the tabs aren't expanding.

Comment: Aha, I'm quite new to Qt so I didn't know about the plugins. It's strange that it doesn't expand the QTabBar at all, I have been playing with it but can't get anything to happen. Please post if you make any progress. Thanks really much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both expanding tabs and coloring the background can be accomplished using style sheets.

For expanding tabs, a style sheet can be applied to the tabs which sets their width to a fraction of the total width of the `QTabWidget`. Since the style sheet will need to be updated upon resize, it is applied using an event filter. See first example code below.

Although the background of the tab bar can be set, the tab bar doesn't fill the entire space above the tab pane. It is the container (or parent widget) which is showing through. To control the coloring of that area, put the `QTabWidget` in a `QWidget` and set the style sheet on the container. See second example code below.

Expanding tabs:

```
#include <QtGui>

// Sets the style sheet of the QTabWidget to expand the tabs.
static void expandingTabsStyleSheet(QTabWidget *tw)
{
    tw->setStyleSheet(QString("QTabBar::tab { width: %1px; } ")
                      .arg(tw->size().width()/tw->count()));
}

// On resize events, reapply the expanding tabs style sheet
class ResizeFilter : public QObject
{
    QTabWidget *target;
public:
    ResizeFilter(QTabWidget *target) : QObject(target), target(target) {}

    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
            expandingTabsStyleSheet(target);
        return false;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QTabWidget *tw = new QTabWidget;
  tw->installEventFilter(new ResizeFilter(tw));
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab1");
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab2");
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab3");

  tw->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Background beside tabs:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget *container = new QWidget;
  container->setStyleSheet("background: qlineargradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2
: 0, stop: 0 black, stop: 1 blue);");

  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(container);
  layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

  QTabWidget *tw = new QTabWidget(container);
  layout->addWidget(tw);
  tw->setStyleSheet(
      "QTabBar::tab { background: gray; color: white; padding: 10px; } "
      "QTabBar::tab:selected { background: lightgray; } "
      "QTabWidget::pane { border: 0; } "
      "QWidget { background: lightgray; } ");
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab1");
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab2");
  tw->addTab(new QWidget, "Tab3");

  container->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, you have two options, depending on what you want to do.

**To fill the background with color:**

Take advantage of the transparency of that portion of the tab widget.

```
QWidget *bg = new QWidget( parent );
bg->setAutoFillBackground( true );
QPalette bg_palette = bg->palette();
bg_palette.setColor( QPalette::Window, QColor( "orange" ) );
bg->setPalette( bg_palette );

QHBoxLayout layout = new QHBoxLayout();
layout->setMargin( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
layout->setSpacing( 0 );
bg->setLayout( layout );

QTabWidget *tab_widget = new QTabWidget();
// set up tab_widget however you want...
layout->addWidget( tab_widget );
```

This makes the bg widget all orange, but since most of the tab widget will draw over the bg widget, you'll only see the orange where the tab widget doesn't draw.

**To make the tabs expand:**

I thought this would be easier than it is, but you basically have to subclass QTabWidget in order to get access to the tab bar widget it uses.

```
class ExpandableTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    Q_PROPERTY( bool expanding_tabs READ Expanding WRITE SetExpanding );

public:
    ExpandableTabWidget( QWidget *parent = NULL ) : QTabWidget( parent )
    {
    }

    bool Expanding() const
    {
        return tabBar()->expanding();
    }

    void SetTabsExpanding( bool expanding = true )
    {
        tabBar()->setExpanding( expanding );
    }
};
```

You would then either need to make your `ExpandableTabWidget` class into a plugin and use it in designer, or you could promote your tab widget to be of type `ExpandableTabWidget` and set the expanding value in code.  If you choose to do the promotion, you won't see the results you want in designer, but you will when you run your program.

Comment: Thanks really much for your ideas! I updated my original question above with some questions regarding the expanding solution, can you please take a look at it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

On qt 4.5 there is a new property that control the tab widget rendering, called **documentMode**. Just call `tabWidget->setDocumentMode(true)` and set the background color of the QTabBar using the stylesheets.

From Qt Documentation:

> This property holds whether or not the tab widget is rendered in a mode suitable for document pages. This is the same as document mode on Mac OS X.
>
> When this property is set the tab widget frame is not rendered. This mode is useful for showing document-type pages where the page covers most of the tab widget area.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem some time ago. I achieved it by making "big" top border, and moving tab bar with margin

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is that I need to have fading on my backgroud otherwise that will work.

Comment: what do you mean by fading? You can set gradient as border color

Comment: Here is example of what can you achieve with Qt CSS: http://pl.tinypic.com/r/24lsn5v/5 and here is CSS: QTabWidget::pane {border: 0; border-top: 30px solid qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 red, stop: 1 yellow); background: yellow; } QTabWidget::tab-bar { top: 30px; }

Answer (score -1):

Alternative option:
Set the width of the individual tabs to 230% to make them fit the lenght of the window.

**QTabBar::tab {

**width: 234%;**

}**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).