# How can I make two rows of tabs in Qt

Tags: qt, tabs, qtabwidget

I would like to have something like the following image. I want two rows of tabs. One is included in the other. Is using two QTabWidget the way to go? Also, I would like to mention that the program's main window will display this structure. If you have any suggestions...

I would like the tabs to look like the following (of course, not exactly; this handmade image is awful).

[Image http://imageshack.us/a/img831/3889/subtabs.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img831/3889/subtabs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested [`QTabWidgets`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html): an outer primary tab which contains its own secondary QTabWidget (where one is necessary).

---

Since you are after specific look, then there are three possible solutions (ordered by complexity) :

1. See what you can do with *Qt style sheets* using nested QTabWidgets. [See this answer for some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513792/1717300), and of course [reference in docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html).
2. Forget QTabWidget, write your own, containing custom tab bar, and using a [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) or just nested [QStackedLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html) for tab contents. You can nest these custom tabbed widgets like you would with QTabWidget, or just have dynamic two-row
   tab bar in one non-nested custom tab widget, it's your code now.
3. Start using QML for UI, perhaps just for a custom tab bar, perhaps for the whole central widget, depending on what you have there.

Comment: Thanks, but can I reach this look with QTabWidgets?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QTabBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtabbar.html) instead. A QTabWidget is formed from a QStackedWidget and a QTabBar, but you can use QTabBars directly - and have two or three or more layers of tabs.