# Tabs in the Pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Which command to use to "break" a row of tabs? I would like to have, for example, 3 tabs in one row and 3 tabs just below it. The skeleton I have referenced as tabs is:

```
# layout tab   
tabs = qg.QTabWidget()

# Create tabs
tab1    = qg.QWidget()  
tab2    = qg.QWidget()
tab3    = qg.QWidget()
tab4    = qg.QWidget()
tab5    = qg.QWidget()
tab6    = qg.QWidget()

tabs.addTab(tab1,"Properties")
tabs.addTab(tab2,"Nodes")
tabs.addTab(tab3,"Bars")
tabs.addTab(tab4,"Restrains") 
tabs.addTab(tab5,"Nodal Loads") 
tabs.addTab(tab6,"Dist.Loads")
```

Here is an example of what I want

[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get

Comment: Here it is! Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple rows tab with QTabWidget in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852739/how-to-create-multiple-rows-tab-with-qtabwidget-in-qt)