# How to create multi tab rows?

Tags: qt-designer, qgis

[image]

I want to make this.
I use Qt Desinger 4.8.5.
how to make tab rows?

Comment: please try something and come with the problem you are facing

Comment: There is no such widget, it has to be created through code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make two rows of tabs in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458256/how-can-i-make-two-rows-of-tabs-in-qt)

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! I certainly wanted to know whether it was possible or not.