# Qt QTabWidget background color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have been trying to set the background color of a QTabWidget to black (or any other color for), but have been unsuccessful in doing so.

[image]

It seems that you need the option autoFillBackground set and then also set "background-color: black;" in the stylesheet. This then displays it properly in the Designer, but fails in the application.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480773/qt-styling-qtabwidget) suggests to enclose it in another QWidget and then use the transparency, but that is a hack around the issue.

How do I set the background color of a QTabWidget via stylesheets?

**EDIT**

Setting `QTabBar { background-color: black; }` results in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem as you, I'm unable to set the tabbar background color as you have described in your edit. My issue is only happening on documentMode in OSX https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#documentMode-prop

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to QTreeWidget, use QTabBar + QStackedWidget and the following stylesheet

```
QTabBar { background-color: black; }
```

or use
[Qt: Styling QTabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480773/qt-styling-qtabwidget)

Comment: Unfortunately this only changes the color behind the tabs and not the one alongside the tabs (see my edit in the main post).